# combined bit and logical operators in c

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bit, logical-operators

I'm confused about some of these operations (combinding bitwise and logical ops).

If x = 0x3F and y = 0x75, find the byte value of the diff c expressions:

```
1) x&y
2) x | y
3) ~x | ~y
4) x & ~y
5) x && y
6) x || y
7) !x || !y
8) x && ~y
```

**attempt**

FIrst, I converted the hex to binary:

```
x = 00111111
y = 01110101
```

**Here are my attemtps**

```
1) 00110101
2) 01111111
3) 01111111
4) x & not y?  isn't the bang operator a logical operator?  what is the bit representation of !y?
5) x && y = TRUE = but how is that represented as a byte? 11111111?
6) x || y = how can this be represented as a byte?
7) !x || y = ???
8) x && ~y = ?????
```

Comment: Your answer to 3 is wrong. `~x` has a one for the first bit, so `~x | ~y` must too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical not operator `!` turns a "true" value into "false", and the other way around. And since any non-zero is considered "true" the operator simple returns zero for anything non-zero.

This leads to `x & !y` to be zero as masking anything with zero is zero.

The logical values for "true" and "false" are specified to be `1` and `0` respectively. This means that the result of a logical operator (i.e. `&&` or `||` or the unary `!`) is always `1` or `0`.

If you combine the two statements above, you get why using double logical-not (`!!`) (which you might have seen somewhere) always returns either `0` or `1`.

Comment: Ok, but what about for number 5?  && is logical, so x && y returns true (as both are non-zero), but what is the bit-representation of the answer? 11111111?

Comment: @JonSmith Read my answer again. Logical operations *always* returns `0` or `1`. The bit-pattern of `0` is `0` and the bit-pattern of `1` is `1`.

Comment: @JonSmith Or `00000000000000000000000000000001` on a 32-bit machine. It doesn't matter how you slice it, one is always one, no matter how many zeroes you put in front, or which base (hex, binary, octal, 36) you use. You would not say the *decimal* value 1 is different from the decimal value 01, would you?

Comment: let's try this way: (NUMBER not Zero) = TRUE, TRUE = 1. Yes, it's not reversable!

Answer (score 0):

## 7)      !x || !y = 0

It's better to think in terms of TRUE and FALSE, for || operator.

```
 X = TRUE, y = TRUE 
 --> !x = FALSE
 --> !y = FALSE
 ----> FALSE OR FALSE = FALSE (0).
```

Comment: And then x && ~y == TRUE && TRUE == TRUE?

Comment: we're approaching :-).  Yes.  Just a note: you'd better write this way:

Comment: x && ~y --> TRUE && TRUE --> TRUE

Comment: actually, in c, "x && ~y == TRUE && TRUE == TRUE" it's a valid expression (the whole line itself!), if you put

Comment: #define TRUE 1         #define FALSE 0